# How to create conditional checkboxes with word template and sharepoint list

Tags: list, infopath, template

I am trying to create a word document using SharePoint lists. I am able to create my word document automatically by using a template and a workflow that transfers my list columns to a list where I have my template set up. I am also able to  populate this document with data from the list. I am not able how ever to create check boxes from that data within the word template. I would like to populate a check box when certain attribute has a certain value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. I used quick fields if clause to make "X" characters to fields. That worked almost but when values changed I had to manually update the field. I corrected this update problem by creating a macro that updates fields automatically.